# PowerShell 5.1: how to extract text from nested HTML elements?

Tags: html, regex, powershell, web-scraping

I am learning web scraping using a [testing website](http://quotes.toscrape.com/) created for that purpose and everything is working fine, for example given this HTML:

```
<small class="author" itemprop="author">Albert Einstein</small>
```

I issue the following command and get True:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $HTML -match '<span class="text" itemprop="text">.*</span>'
True
```

And I also get True when trying to match text within  tags from this HTML:

```
<a href="/" style="text-decoration: none">Quotes to Scrape</a>
```

Here's the command I used:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $HTML -match '<a href=".*">.*</a>'
True
```

However, when trying to match inner text between certain tags from another website and using seemingly similar logic, I get False. The HTML looks like this:

```
<span class="LdapSubMenu">
    <a href="certainHyperLink">
            CertainClientName
         </a>
</span>
```

And the command I issued:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $HTML -match '<span class="LdapSubMenu"><a href=".*">.*</a></span>'
False
```

Given the above mentioned tests which returned True, why my attempt to extract text from "LdapSubMenu" class fails? Does it have something to do with how the elements are nested?

Thank you.

Comment: This `<a href=".*">.*</a>` is the problem, can you spot it ?

Comment: I don't know why it works OK on a standalone element but fails on a nested one

Comment: Try this `(?s)<span class="LdapSubMenu"><a href=".*?">.*?</a></span>`